# Unable to switch between users in Kubuntu 18 with NVidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, xorg, kde

Until now, in Kubuntu 18 pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> allowed me to switch between logged-in users. Now, after installing NVidia drivers few days ago, it stopped working and logs other users out!

Log of `cat ~/.xsession-errors` is:

```
(...)
The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Zasoby chwilowo niedostępne) on X server ":0"
      after 86 requests (86 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
kdeinit5: Fatal IO error: client killed
kdeinit5: sending SIGHUP to children.
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
klauncher: Exiting on signal 1
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
kdeinit5: sending SIGTERM to children.
kdeinit5: Exit.
QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread
QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread
Qt: Dead lock detected while activating a BlockingQueuedConnection: Sender is QObject(0x55dd0c424b50), receiver is QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x7f435c004e80)
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 10 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 11 and type 'Read', disabling...
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
XIO:  fatal IO error 25 (Niewłaściwy ioctl dla urządzenia) on X server ":0"
      after 2096 requests (2096 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Unexpected response from KInit (response = 0).
startkde: Could not start ksmserver. Check your installation.
Error: Can't open display: :0
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.clipboard/contents/ui/ClipboardPage.qml:107:26: Unable to assign [undefined] to QAbstractItemModel*
startkde: Shutting down...
kdeinit5_wrapper: Warning: connect(/run/user/1003/kdeinit5__0) failed: : No such file or directory
Error: Can not contact kdeinit5!
xprop:  unable to open display ':0'
xprop:  unable to open display ':0'
startkde: Done.
```

Nvidia driver version: `430`, tried also `390` with the same problem. Kernel version: `4.15.0-55-generic`.

Uninstalling Nvidia driver solves the issue, but then 3D games are terribly slow, so it's not a solution :-(

Answer (score 0):

After long search the following helped me:

- install Bumblebee: https://float-middle.com/ubuntu-18-04-steam-and-nvidia-390/ (nvidia drivers are loaded only when playing games)
- enable Bumblebee for Steam: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6316-GJKC-7437&l=portuguese

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work on Ubuntu 20 :-(